# How to change window title of console application Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, service, console-application

In Visual Studio i have a console application, however the title always shows as [I think this is debugging specific, question still stands though]:

**file://C:/Users......Service.exe**

We spin up about 12 differently named processes locally and it's a huge pain to find a single one because the paths are so long they only tend to show the first letter or so of the actual process.  We have resorted to hovering over them on the taskbar to see the full path.  So my question is how do we go from the above (and example below) to something like:

**Service**

Example -

[image: Example]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using C#, use Console.Title and the string methods like trim or whatever.

Comment: My apologies, I solved this using `Console.Title = "Desired Title"`.  However we deploy services using TopShelf and this caused an issue, so I had to surround these blocks with an `#if DEBUG`