# How can I hide my project path string that appear on the top and after every run in console in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How can I hide my project path string that appear on the top and after every run in console in visual studio

[image: project path]

[image: project path at the top of the console]

I tried to call `Console.ReadKey();` //not work .. actually it is the second photo

and some other failed tries

Comment: See [How do I hide the path in command line prompt on Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/315354/85113)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change window title of console application Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36284895/how-to-change-window-title-of-console-application-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add the following two pieces of code:

```
        Console.Title = "";

        

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Here is the original code:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");


    }
}
```

The output is:

[image]

Here is the added code:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        Console.Title = "";

        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

The output is:

[image]

Of course, you can also use Console.Title = ""; enter the title you want